# Software design/Firebase: Rendering list of lessons associated with user's progress

Tags: firebase, software-design

I’m building a simple duolingo clone that saves user progress in each course. However, I’m not sure if the solution I came up with is the best way to implement this feature. I described both the feature and my solution idea at the bottom. Would appreciate any input or advice!

### How it will work:

1. Fetch all courses

[image]

- the main homepage renders the list of all courses available that is fetched from firestore `/courses`

2. Fetch all lessons

[image]

- When you click Course 1, it will redirect to `/courses/course-1/` which then shows the list of lessons that is fetched again from firestore `/courses/course-1`

1. Display user progress along with completedDate

[image]

- here’s where I’m stuck: I want to render the list of lessons in a way that shows which lessons user has already completed and track the progress
- however, this is not possible at the moment because I am simply rendering a list of lessons from the database that is not bound to userId.

This is where I’m at solving this :

- create a progress object for each user which is a copy of course object with additional fields: `completed, completedDate, and createdObjectId`. createdObjectId will save the id of created lesson object once user finishes that lesson.

```markdown
{
        title: "Lesson 1"
        desc: "description of lesson 1"
        completed: False
        completedDate: null
        createdObjectId: null
}
```

- This progress object will be created when user first makes a get request for that course. (If progress doesn’t exist, create one now)
- Now when users go to `/courses/course-1/`, fetch the user progress data from firestore `/users/{userId}/progress/course-1` instead of `/courses/course-1/`

Comment: That model sounds sensible, so I'd say go for it!